# Navigation Drawer back button Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, materialdrawer

I am using this binding for this awesome Material Drawer Library by MikePenz.

I have implemented the Navigation Drawer with this library and I have also managed to change the hamburger menu to the back arrow when I go level deep. Now I have some problems to get the back arrow to work correctly. When I click on the back arrow, rather than going back to the previous page, it opens up the navigation drawer.

After looking into the original library, I have identified, the following code is responsible to manage the back arrow button. I would appreciate , if someone can help me a bit to write this listener code in C#.

```
.withOnDrawerNavigationListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerNavigationListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationClickListener(View clickedView) {
                    //this method is only called if the Arrow icon is shown. The hamburger is automatically managed by the MaterialDrawer
                    //if the back arrow is shown. close the activity
                    AdvancedActivity.this.finish();
                    //return true if we have consumed the event
                    return true;
                }
            })
```

Here is the binding libray that I use : [MaterialDrawer-Xamarin](https://github.com/amatkivskiy/MaterialDrawer-Xamarin)

And this is the link to the original Library : [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/AdvancedActivity.java/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var result = new DrawerBuilder()
        .WithActivity(this)
        .AddDrawerItems(
          //Add some items here
          new DividerDrawerItem()
        )
        .WithOnDrawerNavigationListener(this);
```

and implement `Drawer.IOnDrawerNavigationListener` in your activity like this:

```
public bool OnNavigationClickListener(View clickedView)
{
    this.Finish();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I get this error. when I try your code. Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Mikepenz.MaterialDrawer.DrawerBuilder.WithOnDrawerNavigationListener(Mikepenz.MaterialDrawer.Drawer.IOnDrawerNavigationListener)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502)

Comment: My appologies, That works. Its just that I forgot to inherit the interface